# How to add space after string and remove a space?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do you add a space after and string and remove the space in python?

Example of string:

```
    FROM = "Leeds Bradford"

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys(FROM)
```

It's a bit wierd but what happens is that when I open an application, I don't know if it is because of a cookie but it autofills a text box with exisiting data, so what I tried and do is clear the textbox but it doesn't recognise Leeds Bradford (an automatic dropdown should appear for the option). Manually if I add a space after the word and remove the space, then the drop down appears

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what results are you expecting?

Comment: Append space? `string + ' '`. Remove trailing whitespace? `string.rstrip()`. For anything more specific you'll have to clarify your question.

Comment: Isn't adding a space and removing a space, exactly the same as doing nothing at all?

Comment: Do you want to send a " " to input field and then imitate `Backspace` button pressing before entering actual data?

Comment: @Andersson Yeah please if you know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if following do the trick

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys(' ')
depart_from.send_keys(u'\ue003')
depart_from.send_keys(FROM)
```

Comment: It seems to do what I asked from i nthe question but it doesn't select from the drop down menu for some strange reason. Don't know if you can help me but how come when it opens the browser, it adds text in the textbox? I know it does this if i did not use selenium so it seems to be the browser maybe remembering a cookie (but yet it opens in seperate browser so should be like fresh). Do you know a way of ensuring the textbox will always be clear (so the text doesn't appear in the first place rather than let it appear, clear it and then enter in our text?)

Comment: Why aren't you using Keys.BACKSPACE here?